# Which way is it preferred to call a parent's update function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component, `<MoneyCounter onChange={this.onCounterChange}>`.

The parent Component, `App`, naturally passes the onCounterChange down to `MoneyCounter`. `MoneyCounter` itself has multiple callbacks for its internal buttons, so I could (1) call `this.props.onChange()` in EACH of those callbacks (this is an option I do not like, I'd rather just call it in one central place that knows state is updating), *or* I could call it in `componentWillUpdate` / `componentWillUpdate` / `componentShouldUpdate`.

Now, the problem first arises that if I call it in any of those latter 3 options, my `App` callback calls `setState` on itself and it put it in an infinite loop. HOWEVER I then made a change to my `onCounterChange` callback in App so that it doesn't call `setState` when it doesn't need to, which fixed the infinite loop bug.

A third option is actually overriding `this.setState` in `MoneyCounter`, something like this in the constructor:

```
    let oldSet = this.setState;
    this.setState = function() {
        let args = Array.from(arguments);
        args.push(() => {
            this.props.onChange(this.props.unitValue, this.state.count);
        });
        oldSet.apply(this, args);
    }
```

Which I've checked and it works, but it's maybe not nice.

What's the proper react way to do it?

Comment: why do you have `let oldSet = this.setState;` Provide more code if you can.

Comment: because I'm changing the meaning of `this.setState`, but I still want to call what it used to mean

Comment: so line 7 is essentially `this.setState({ .apply(this,args) })` which makes no sense

Comment: @Omar: It's a perfectly standard way to wrap a function: You grab the old function, assign a new one to the property it used to be on, and then from within your new function call the old one as appropriate. (And no, Line 7 is not that.)